# Send Large file over the network using Soap web services in Java

Tags: java, php, web-services, file, soap

I have to send file with atleast 100MB size over the network using Soap Web Services on the PHP server side  from our java code. What is the most efficient way to send file over the network so that the network traffic become less. 
I have read about `byte range request/byte serving` but i don't know how to apply in web services.
and is there any other way for web service response chunking?

Comment: Back in the day we did send it as a multipart HTTP message (no link sorry, it was a long time ago), the SOAP message was the first one and the files would be "attachments". Base64Encode is also possible, but rather inefficient.

Comment: Also, `byte serving` is part of HTTP, not of SOAP. Do not mix layers, it just makes no sense.